# Finding a max value restricted by Date

Tags: date, lookup

First of all thank you for the treasure of information! I have found many answers so far but I have run into an issue I cannot solve.

I run a database with vehicles involved and beginning mileage is something I would like to automate. I have tabs all keeping a tally of beginning and ending mileage based on a query of the main index of all trips. I have been using a vlookup function but I have found that it is quite fragile (amongst other calculations) and I have been converting them over to script in the hopes that it remains more robust (ie accidentally typing in a calculated field....which wipes thousands of trips in a single stroke. Since they are Vlookup currently I have to go back and systematically restore the correct calculation (takes a couple of hours to do).

My first attempt is here:

1: On the main page I would utilize vlookup which I restricted with a status:

```
=arrayformula(if(M2:M="Ready",vlookup(J2:J2287,'Vehicle Lifecycle'!$A$2:$L$30,7,false),O2:O2287))
```

2: On the Vehicle Lifecycle page I utilized a max formula which looks up the max mileage constantly for maintenance costs per mile:

```
=max('C-2'!$F$2:$F)
```

I would like to script a restriction with a date (meaning it doesn't look up a max after the date of the trip).

Or, if it might be more direct, find a way to lookup the last previous trip with the vehicle and pull the ending mileage.

Currently I have this as a script but I am just getting started with scripting so forgive my ignorance. I am a quick study however and so far I am doing well...ish

```
function myfunction() 
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var lr = ss.getLastRow();
 
 
 ss.getRange("O2").setFormula("=iferror(max(indirect(\"'\"&J2&\"'!$F$2:$F\")),\"\")");
 var filldownrange = ss.getRange(2,15, lr-1);
 ss.getRange("O2").copyTo(filldownrange)
}
```

This is perfect for pulling the max value from the appropriate tab so I'm close. Can anyone help me get the cigar?

Comment: Check your tags. That script isn't  VBA.

Comment: I didn't put in any tags that I remember but I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!! I started working with a formula and I bumped into a problem when I looked for just the date on vlookup. The solution was subtracting 1 from the date and looking for that.

```
 function onVehicleSelection() 
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var lr = ss.getLastRow();
 
 
 ss.getRange("O2").setFormula("=iferror(vlookup(to_date(minus(C2,1)),indirect(\"'\"&J2&\"'!$B$2:G\"),5,true),\"\")")
 var filldownrange = ss.getRange(2,15, lr-1);
 ss.getRange("O2").copyTo(filldownrange)
}
```

However if someone has a more elegant solution I would be interested to hear it. I could definitely use some pointers on triggers as I will be working on those after I figure out how to do about 8 more calculations in script. So far I have been lucky enough to have functions that translate nicely.